# ADFS integration - user session creation without the user creation

Tags: users, sessions

I did not find my answer after reading some articles.

For the user authentication, my Drupal site needs to communicate with a SAML IdP (ADFS).

I have **an additional requirement**: The user must be authenticated against the IdP and the Drupal user session must be created **without a Drupal user is available or created in DB**.

The definition of its roles would be evaluated on the basis of AD group at session creation time.

So far, I found the [simpleSAMLphp Authentication module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth) that manages this type of authentication BUT it needs to create a Drupal user (manually or automatically).

Other modules I viewed follow the same logic.

Someone knows how implementing the additional requirement?